# How do I work out the distance of Venus orbit mathematically?

Tags: integration, elliptic-curves, elliptic-equations

How do I work out the distance Venus travels in one orbit mathematically? I know the parametric equations for its ellipse but I need to work out the total distance travelled in its orbital period.

Comment: So, in other words, you want to calculate the perimeter of the ellipse, right?

Comment: Yes, do you know how to do that?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on ellipses has a section on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference. TLDR: It's a bit tricky to calculate.